# Views sorting by number of values in field

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have a content type with an text field with unlimited number of values.

I have a view for that content type and I want to sort it by number of values in that field.

How can I do that in Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable Aggregation in View settings.
2. Add Your Multiple Field in Sort Criteria
3. Select Count as Aggregation Settings
4. Select Sort Criteria - Asc , Desc

PS: Do not add same field to field list , it will lead to multiple results in the view