# How do I enable aggregation in the settings?

Tags: views

I have the same problem as in [Views sorting by number of values in field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104903/views-sorting-by-number-of-values-in-field)".  I would really like to try the solution that is given.

How can I enable aggregation in the view settings? I can't find it anywhere.

The following is a screenshot of the view panel. Is there any other name for "aggregation"?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a search API view? Those don't support aggregation, probably because of the pluggable backend

Comment: It is! So do you know some other solution? 
What I want to do is this: "I have a content type with an text field with unlimited number of values.I have a view for that content type and I want to sort it by number of values in that field." Thanks

Comment: Don't use Search API for the view, use a regular content type view, and then you'll have aggregation available.

Answer (score 0):

Your view appears to be a search API view, for which "aggregation" is not supported. Which is also why the "Use aggregation" option is not visible (credits: comment to question [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive)).

A possible solution (work around?) to make the aggregation option available, is to NOT use the Search API for your view, and instead use a regular content type view (credits: comment to question [Alfred Armstrong](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13727/alfred-armstrong)).

**PS**: Comments may get deleted, for all sorts of reasons, which is why I included them in this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question now, but posting in case anyone comes here looking to do the same thing in D8 with a Search API view.

With D8 version of Search API, when making the index you can add a General field `Aggregated field`.

[image: General fields list showing the Aggregated Field available]

In the setting of this field, simply select `Count` as the aggregation type and select the field you want to count.

[image: Aggregated field settings showing the Count option]

Remember to set the type to `Integer` when looking at the list of added fields.
[image: General Aggregated Field in Search API Index]

This will provide a new field in the search View that will display a count of the selected field for that row.

[image: Search API View field of the aggregated count field]